# How do I delete all percolator queries in an Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica, elasticsearch-percolate

I wish to delete all the percolator queries on an index, but leave the documents intact.

Is there an easy way to perform this?

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile this is fixed. The following command will delete all the percoaltor queries:

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/my-index/.percolator/_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Percolator is special type with name `.percolator` in your index.

Every query registered in percolator is just a document in this type.

Knowing this fact, you can delete all queries from percolator like this:

```
$client = new Elastica\Client();
$index = $client->getIndex('myindex');
$percolator = $index->getType('.percolator');
$percolator->delete();
```

Comment: So how will you go about deleting an individual query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be able to use [delete-by-query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) and the [match-all](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) query on the `.percolator` type of the index. This does not work and is a long-reported ES bug (see [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1712) and then [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/7052)).

The next best solution is to run a query against the `.percolator` type and then loop over the results, deleting each percolator document individually.

(Edited because initial answer was wrong.)